# Prevent Git Gui from highlighting trailing spaces

Tags: windows, git

Git Gui shows spaces at the end of line highlighted with red; how can I turn off this feature?

Comment: I use neither Windows nor most GUIs, but with the command line interface this is controlled by the `core.whitespace` setting [in `git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  It would be sensible for the GUI to use the same control knob.

Comment: @torek, it worked. Why don't make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently (see comments) Git Gui uses the same control knob here as plain command-line git, namely the `core.whitespace` setting, as described in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> `core.whitespace`
>   
>   
>   A comma separated list of common whitespace problems to notice. *`git diff`* will use `color.diff.whitespace` to highlight them, and *`git apply --whitespace=error`* will consider them as errors. You can prefix `-` to disable any of them (e.g. `-trailing-space`):
>
> - `blank-at-eol` treats trailing whitespaces at the end of the line as an error (enabled by default).
> - `space-before-tab` treats a space character that appears immediately before a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (enabled by default).
> - `indent-with-non-tab` treats a line that is indented with space characters instead of the equivalent tabs as an error (not enabled by default).
> - `tab-in-indent` treats a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (not enabled by default).
> - `blank-at-eof` treats blank lines added at the end of file as an error (enabled by default).
> - `trailing-space` is a short-hand to cover both `blank-at-eol` and `blank-at-eof`.
> - `cr-at-eol` treats a carriage-return at the end of line as part of the line terminator, i.e. with it, `trailing-space` does not trigger if the character before such a carriage-return is not a whitespace (not enabled by default).
> - `tabwidth=<n>` tells how many character positions a tab occupies; this is relevant for `indent-with-non-tab` and when Git fixes `tab-in-indent` errors. The default tab width is 8. Allowed values are 1 to 63.

(I'm not sure how Git Gui allows you to modify the config, or whether you must do that from a command line.  Presumably you want `-trailing-space` in this case, or maybe just `-blank-at-eol`.)